# AngularJS routing doesn't work in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angularjs, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework Core with VS Code and want to implement AngularJS to my project. I have got CRUD manipulations to work. I have the only issue to get angular routing to work. Having the error:

> GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/Templates/Form.html 404 (Not
>   Found)

Check out my code, kinda wondering where is the issue:

**app.js ROUTING PART (all controllers work)**

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'Templates/list.html',
    controller: 'pController'
})
$routeProvider.when('/form', {
    templateUrl: '/Templates/Form.html',
    controller: 'pFormController'
})});
```

**Index.cshtml** ng-app and src links are in _Layout

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl"> 
<p>{{ 1+2 }}</p>
<p>{{ word }}</p>
<a href="#/list">List</a>
<br />
<a href="#/form">Add Employee Form</a>

<div ng-view></div>
```

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0-rc2/angular-material.min.js"></script> 

   <script src="~/js/SPA/app.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
   <script src="~/js/SPA/ctrl.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
   <script src="~/js/SPA/pController.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
   <script src="~/js/SPA/pFormController.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
   <script src="~/js/SPA/pFormEditController.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
   <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

   <script src="~/js/SPA/pService.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Link to github project: https://github.com/luchkax/portfolio/tree/master/AngularASP.NET/employeesFactory

**UPDATE**

What I figured is when I do .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'}) so it is actually works then, redirects to the homepage http://127.0.0.1:5000/ . There definitely an issue with templates path location...

**UPDATE 2**

Solution was: provide app.js routing template files path starting /js/SPA/Templates/... Angular recognized only that one kind for me.

```
$routeProvider.when('/list', {
    templateUrl: '/js/SPA/Templates/list.html',
    controller: 'pController'
})
$routeProvider.when('/Form', {
    templateUrl: '/js/SPA/Templates/Form.html',
    controller: 'pFormController'
})
```

Comment: entity framwork is an orm - you are using mvc.

Comment: FYI, `.chtml`(Razor Views) doesn't accessible via URL, you have to get them via MVC controller's action, which return ActionResult. Even if you add `.html` files views folder, they isn't accessible by URL(by MVC design).. Create a folder with different name and put all html files into it

Comment: don't request through the `views` folder

Comment: @DanielA.White Views folder is created folder by me in my SPA folder, not the one in original Views folder

Comment: @PankajParkar but I do not want the MVC server requests for routing. I want AngularJs only no server rendering.

Comment: @Nash don't use cshtml then. consider using webpack or something similar

Comment: @DanielA.White alright, changed all my template location to '/wwwroot/js/SPA/Templates/...' and changed .cshtml to .html  and same problem still

Comment: @PankajParkar I did exactly what you mentioned. And the problem still unsolved. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @DanielA.White can I have a chat with you sir?

Comment: Try not including wwwroot in the url

Comment: @DanielA.White YES! That worked! Thank you!